# Execution of a script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this situation. I had done a script few month ago that is still running on a google sites. The doGet Function is :

```
    function doGet(e) {
  var myapp = UiApp.createApplication();


 var mygrid = myapp.createGrid(5, 2);
  var listboxAssociazione=myapp.createListBox().setId("listboxAssociazione").setName("listboxAssociazione");
  var labelAssociazione=myapp.createLabel("Associazione").setId("Associazione");
  var listboxMeseFatturato=myapp.createListBox().setId("listboxMeseFatturato").setName("listboxMeseFatturato");
  var labelMeseFatturato=myapp.createLabel("Mese da fatturare").setId("Mese da fatturare");
  var listboxAnnoFatturato=myapp.createListBox().setId("listboxAnnoFatturato").setName("listboxAnnoFatturato");
  var labelAnnoFatturato=myapp.createLabel("Anno").setId("Anno");
  var buttonCalcola=myapp.createButton().setText("Calcola").setId("CalcolaFattura");
  var labelLavoroInCorso=myapp.createLabel("").setId("labelLavoroInCorso").setStyleAttribute('color', 'blue');


  mygrid.setWidget(0, 0,labelAssociazione);
  mygrid.setWidget(0, 1, listboxAssociazione);
  mygrid.setWidget(1, 0, labelMeseFatturato);
  mygrid.setWidget(1, 1, listboxMeseFatturato);
  mygrid.setWidget(2, 0, labelAnnoFatturato);
  mygrid.setWidget(2, 1, listboxAnnoFatturato); 
  mygrid.setWidget(3, 1, buttonCalcola);
  mygrid.setWidget(4, 1, labelLavoroInCorso);

  var p=DocsList.getFolders();
  var totcartelle = p.length;
  var trovato= false;
  var cartellaAssociazioni;
  for(var j=0;j<totcartelle && trovato==false;j++){
    var prova=p[j].getId();
    if(p[j].getId()=="0B-H4Ioaio5w5YTg3MGFkOWQtMzYzNy00ZTFhLWEzY2YtZTVlNzIwYWJhMmJm"){
    trovato=true;
     cartellaAssociazioni=p[j]; 
    }

  }

  var cartelle =cartellaAssociazioni.getFolders();
   var lunghezza = cartelle.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < lunghezza; i++) //these arrays are zero based it looks like
   { var prova=cartelle[i].getName();
    listboxAssociazione.addItem(prova); 
   }


  //Aggiunta dei mesi alla listbox
  listboxMeseFatturato.addItem("Gennaio");
  listboxMeseFatturato.addItem("Febbraio");
  listboxMeseFatturato.addItem("Marzo");
  listboxMeseFatturato.addItem("Aprile");
  listboxMeseFatturato.addItem("Maggio");
  listboxMeseFatturato.addItem("Giugno");
  listboxMeseFatturato.addItem("Luglio");
  listboxMeseFatturato.addItem("Agosto");
  listboxMeseFatturato.addItem("Settembre");
  listboxMeseFatturato.addItem("Ottobre");
  listboxMeseFatturato.addItem("Novembre");
  listboxMeseFatturato.addItem("Dicembre");

  //Aggiunta dell'anno di fatturazione
  var d= new Date();
  var annoAttuale=parseInt(d.getFullYear());
  listboxAnnoFatturato.addItem(""+annoAttuale);
  listboxAnnoFatturato.addItem(""+(annoAttuale-1));


  var formpanel=myapp.createFormPanel().setId("form");


  var serverClickHandler = myapp.createServerClickHandler('GeneraFattura');
  serverClickHandler.addCallbackElement(formpanel);
  buttonCalcola.addClickHandler(serverClickHandler);

  var serverClickHandlerStatus = myapp.createServerClickHandler('ChangeStatus');
  serverClickHandlerStatus.addCallbackElement(formpanel);
  buttonCalcola.addClickHandler(serverClickHandlerStatus);




  formpanel.add(mygrid);
  myapp.add(formpanel);
  return myapp;
}


//Function to disable the button to avoid double click
function ChangeStatus(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById("labelLavoroInCorso").setText("Attendere! Calcolo della richiesta di pagamento in corso...");
  app.getElementById("CalcolaFattura").setEnabled(false);
  return app;
}
```

Now my problem is that when i click the button "Calcola" in the site, it seems that the  function "GeneraFattura" runs a number of random times instead of 1.

If i run the same function from the script editor in Google site with the same 3 parameter given by me

```
var valoreAssociazione = "Volley";
var valoreMese="May";
var valoreAnno = "2012";
```

instead from the form above, it works correctly.

When i say it works correctly i mean that in the function "GeneraFattura" there is only one line where i copy a spreadsheet. If i run the script from the script editor the output is one copy of the spreadsheet, if i run the script from the sites i get 5 6 copy of the spreadsheet.

Where do you think is the problem??Why a different behaviour between google sites script editor execution and the script execution embedded in the google site??

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug that we are actively working on. Handlers that run more than 30 seconds may end up being called up to 3 times. See this issue:

http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1504

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is the actual reason of your issue but the method `createServerClickHandler()`
is in the [list of deprecated members](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_uiinstance?hl=fr-FR#createServerClickHandler) so I'd suggest to replace it as recommended.

Should be like this :  *(same modification for both handlers of course ;-)*

```
  var serverClickHandler = myapp.createServerHandler('GeneraFattura');
  buttonCalcola.addClickHandler(serverClickHandler);
  serverClickHandler.addCallbackElement(formpanel);
```

Note : I would also suggest another approach to avoid multiple click on your button using a client handler.  It could go like this :

```
    //Client Handler to disable the button to avoid double click (insert in the UI definition function)
      var msg = app.getElementById("labelLavoroInCorso").setText("Attendere! Calcolo della richiesta di pagamento in corso...").setVisible(false);
      var Clienthandler = app.createClientHandler()
         .forEventSource().setEnabled(false);
         .forTargets(msg).setVisible(true);
         buttonCalcola.addClickHandler(Clienthandler)
    // then at the end of the serverhandler function you will have to re-enable the button and setVisible(false) the message
```

EDIT : the interrest of the client handler is that it has immediate effect, when you use 2 server handlers you cannot be sure which one will execute first. It also gives a better user experience because of the immediate responsiveness (well, that's my opinion ;-)